# i am trying to save the image using the `Intervention \ Image library`. and I found an error Image source is not readable

Tags: php, laravel

> ```
>  public function store(Request $request)
>     {
>       
>         $this->validate($request, [
>             'judul'       => 'required',
>             'category_id' => 'required',
>             'konten'     => 'required',
>             'gambar'      => 'required',
>         ]);
>
>         $gambar = $request->gambar;
>         $new_gambar = time().$gambar->getClientOriginalName();
>         
>         $post = Posts::create([
>             'judul'       => $request->judul,
>             'category_id' => $request->category_id,
>             'konten'      => $request->konten,
>             'gambar'      =>  'public/uploads/posts/'.$new_gambar,
>             'slug'        => Str::slug($request->judul),
>             'users_id'    => Auth::id()
>         ]);
>
>         $img = Image::make('public/uploads/',$gambar->getRealPath())->resize(300,
> ```
>
> 300)->save('public/uploads/', $gambar->getClientOriginalName());
> $gambar->move('uploads', $new_gambar);
> $post->tags()->attach($request->tags);
>
> ```
>         return redirect('post');
>     }
> ```

Comment: try with `public_path()`  instead of `public/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add enctype in your html form

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

And change for this in your controller:

```
$img = Image::make($request->file('gambar')->getRealPath());
```

> Also check permissions of the directory in which you are uploading the file

Answer (score 0):

make sure form has enctype:

```
<form class="form" ... enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

change controller

```
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;

public function store(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request, [
    // 'judul'       => 'required',
    //if judul column type is varchar need to set max varchar value or less
    //varchar max 255, if higer than 255 strings, extra string will be truncated
    'judul'       => 'required|string|max:200', 
    // 'category_id' => 'required',
    //category should exist
    'category_id' => 'required|exists:categories,id',
    'konten'      => 'required',
    // 'gambar'      => 'required',
    //validating image is successfully uploaded and is image format
    'gambar'      => 'required|file|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
    //validation for tags, assuming 1 input <select name="tags[]" multiple="multiple"/>
    'tags'        => 'array',
    'tags.*'        => 'exists:tags,id'//each value of input select exists in tags table
  ]);

  // $gambar = $request->gambar; 
  //get the file from <input type="file" name="gambar"/>
  $gambar = $request->file('gambar'); 
  $new_gambar = time().$gambar->getClientOriginalName();
  //make path to save image: sample public path
  $file_path = public_path("uploads/post/{$new_gambar}"); 

  $img = Image::make($gambar)
  ->resize(300,300)
  ->save($file_path);

  $post = Posts::create([
    'judul'       => $request->judul,
    'category_id' => $request->category_id,
    'konten'      => $request->konten,
    // 'gambar'      =>  'public/uploads/posts/'.$new_gambar,
    //should maake the image first
    'gambar'      => $file_path,
    'slug'        => Str::slug($request->judul),
    'users_id'    => Auth::id() // <- if it is to get current logged in user, use  Auth::user()->id
  ]);

  // $gambar->move('uploads', $new_gambar); //let Intervention do this for you
  // $post->tags()->attach($request->tags); 
  //if tags exists (get values frominput select)
  $post->tags()->sync($request->input('tags', []));
  //$request->input('tags', []) <- if input tags is not null get value, else use empty array
  //if route have name e.g Route::get('post', 'PostController@post')->name('post');
  //return redirect()->route('post');
  return redirect('post');
}
```